# React app freezing after iterating over array in component return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dayjs

I'm working on adding a calendar feature to my React application. I'm using [this](https://youtu.be/5jRrVqRWqsM) tutorial to do it. I'm trying to use [Day.js](https://day.js.org/en/) instead of Moment, because Moment is in legacy mode, and Day.js was one of the recommendations. It seems that most of the functionality is the same.

Here is my basic calendar component:

```
const Calendar = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(moment());
  const [calendar, setCalendar] = useState([]);
  const startDay = value.clone().startOf("month").startOf("week");
  const endDay = value.clone().endOf("month").endOf("week");

  useEffect(() => {
    const day = startDay.clone().subtract(1, "day");
    const a = [];
    while (day.isBefore(endDay, "day")) {
      a.push(
        Array(7)
          .fill(0)
          .map(() => day.add(1, "day").clone())
      );
    }
    setCalendar(a);
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Calendar will go here.</h1>
      <div>
        {calendar.map((week) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {week.map((day) => {
                return <div>{day.format("D").toString()}</div>;
              })}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

Before I started to map through the `calendar` array, I only had the `<h1>` tag in the return, and the component rendered as I expected. I also previously printed out the values of `startDay` and `endDay`. However when I include the logic to map over the calendar array, the whole application locks up on me. I have to comment out that code and restart my server to reset everything. I'm having trouble figuring out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that `day.isBefore(endDay, "day")` condition is never met. I doubt `day.add(1, "day")` actually mutates the `day` variable: it most likley returns a new instance.

Just checked the docs for [`add`](https://day.js.org/docs/en/manipulate/add):

> "Returns a cloned Day.js object with a specified amount of time
> added."

That means you will need to use `let` to declare the `day` variable and re-assign it when adding days.

Comment: That's the problem when relying on side-effects and switching libraries. In momentjs `add` does actually mutate the current instance, but in dayjs it does not.

Comment: @Thomas  I hate librairies with APIs that mutate objects that conceptually are **values**. Entities are fine to change, but not values!